# Looping over a json in ansible and using the json data to run tasks in parallel

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I have the following requirement.

- loop over a json data
- Use the above data to run tasks in parallel

Example: My json data is as follows

```json
{
 "xyx": 
    {
    "hostname": "xyz",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "welcome1",
    "password2": "welcome2",
    "version": "19.17",
    "toversion" : "19.18",
    "netconf": "bond",
    "baseversion": "18.8"
    },
"abc": {
    "hostname": "abc",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "welcome1",
    "password2": "welcome2",
    "version": "19.17",
    "toversion" : "19.18",
    "netconf": "bond",
    "baseversion": "18.8"
  }
}
```

I need to run the following task in both hostnames `abc` and `xyz` in parallel

```yaml
- name: Image a system
  command: python3 image.pyc "{{ hostname }}" {{ version }}
```

Can someone please help achieve this ?

I tried to loop over the json but not sure how to use it in the tasks to run in parallel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Are you getting an error? here is a [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that may be useful to you

Answer (score 2):

Given the dictionary in the variable *images*. Either use the filter *dict2items*

```yaml
- name: Image a system
  command: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.value.hostname }} {{ item.value.version }}"
  loop: "{{ images|dict2items }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

, or get the values from the dictionary

```yaml
- name: Image a system
  command: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.hostname }} {{ item.version }}"
  loop: "{{ images.values()|list }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Optionally, you can create a dictionary for this purpose. Declare the below variable in *vars* as appropriate

```yaml
  hostname_version: "{{ images.values()|list|
                        items2dict(key_name='hostname',
                                   value_name='version') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hostname_version:
    abc: '19.17'
    xyz: '19.17'
```

Then, the task below should give the same results

```yaml
- name: Image a system
  command: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ hostname_version|dict2items }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    images:
      abc:
        baseversion: '18.8'
        hostname: abc
        netconf: bond
        password: welcome1
        password2: welcome2
        toversion: '19.18'
        username: root
        version: '19.17'
      xyx:
        baseversion: '18.8'
        hostname: xyz
        netconf: bond
        password: welcome1
        password2: welcome2
        toversion: '19.18'
        username: root
        version: '19.17'

    hostname_version: "{{ images.values()|list|
                          items2dict(key_name='hostname',
                                     value_name='version') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.value.hostname }} {{ item.value.version }}"
      loop: "{{ images|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.hostname }} {{ item.version }}"
      loop: "{{ images.values()|list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.hostname }}"

    - debug:
        var: hostname_version

    - debug:
        msg: "python3 image.pyc {{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ hostname_version|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
ok: [localhost] => (item=xyx) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc xyz 19.17

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
ok: [localhost] => (item=xyz) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc xyz 19.17

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hostname_version:
    abc: '19.17'
    xyz: '19.17'

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'abc', 'value': '19.17'}) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'xyz', 'value': '19.17'}) => 
  msg: python3 image.pyc xyz 19.17

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"How do I run the tasks in parallel?"***

A: Run the tasks in the loop asynchronously. See [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling). For example, to test the timing, the playbook below runs the command *sleep 3*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    images:
      abc:
        baseversion: '18.8'
        hostname: abc
        netconf: bond
        password: welcome1
        password2: welcome2
        toversion: '19.18'
        username: root
        version: '19.17'
      xyx:
        baseversion: '18.8'
        hostname: xyz
        netconf: bond
        password: welcome1
        password2: welcome2
        toversion: '19.18'
        username: root
        version: '19.17'

    hostname_version: "{{ images.values()|list|
                          items2dict(key_name='hostname',
                                     value_name='version') }}"

  tasks:

    - command:
        cmd: "sleep 3"
        #cmd: "echo python3 image.pyc {{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ hostname_version|dict2items }}"
      register: async_out
      async: 5
      poll: 0
    - debug:
        var: async_out
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      loop: "{{ async_out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.key }}"
      register: async_poll
      until: async_poll.finished
      retries: 5
    - debug:
        var: async_poll
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for result in async_poll.results %}
          {{ result.item.item.key }} {{ result.start }} {{ result.end }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************

TASK [command] ************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'abc', 'value': '19.17'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'xyz', 'value': '19.17'})

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [async_status] *******************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: async_status (5 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=abc)
changed: [localhost] => (item=xyz)

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    abc 2023-01-24 13:17:48.526694 2023-01-24 13:17:51.530734
    xyz 2023-01-24 13:17:48.831822 2023-01-24 13:17:51.836860

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

From the last debug you see that:

- The second command started *0.3s* after the first one
- The first command finished *2.7s* after the second one started

This is the "best effort" parallelism you can get in Ansible.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, now how do I run the tasks in parallel. So, that ,
1. If a task on host1 fails, others tasks should not execute.
2. host2 should continue to execute other tasks irrespective of failures in host1


    tasks:
    - name: Image Server(s)         
      command: python3 image.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}}
      async: 720
      poll: 90
      with_dict: "{{input}}"

    - name: configure system
      command: python3 firstnet.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}} {{item.value.netconf}}
      async: 100
      poll: 30
      with_dict: "{{input}}"

Comment: I added the example.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Botka, but I was looking for a slightly different information. I guess I would have to make it more clear .. Let me open another question and check there.